Azure DevOps Build pipeline failing at Publish step after upgraded to .NET 8
I am trying to upgrade my ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to .NET 8.
We have ReactJS as a front end and using node 16.16.0 version which were working fine on .NET Core 2.2 project.
After project upgrade to .NET 8, it's working fine on my local machine. But, in Azure DevOps build pipeline, it's failing at the "Publish" step.
In the old version, the build pipeline was using Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.3+2f374e28e for .NET
Now with .NET 8 (VS2022), it's using MSBuild version 17.9.4+90725d08d for .NET.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Common/button.tsx:30:20 TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'JSX'. ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/AdminTool/GameId.tsx:81:52 TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type 'LinkProps | Readonly

I need solution and code for solving this error

How are you specifying the version of node to use?

And which VM image are you using?

Did you also upgrade the dependent libraries to suite with .NET8? Try to check update the namespace 'JSX' to the latest version. And ensure you have set your project to use the new versions of the libraries.

have you installed the ts-loader? If yes then update your pipeline configuration so that it includes ts-loader for handling  the TypeScript file
